# Why run into ANR crash when using debug mode

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging

When I use debug mode and evaluate some value about 5 to 10 seconds, the app crash.

This looks like an ANR error.

Shouldn't the thread be suspended when using debug mode?

How to solve it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue thanks to this comment
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37442098/2021570

In my case it was a problem with breakpoint configuration. My default configuration was "Suspend :Thread" and when I switched to "Suspend: All" it started working.

Comment: Thanks. I change to "Suspend: All", but still crashs.

Comment: Mine was already suspend all. Still the issue persist. When i debug in other device, it works. Is it device specific issue?